# python TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python-3.x

```
import time

for i in range(2,6):
    start = time.time()
    n=i

    end = time.time()
    print(n)

    time_cost=end-start
    print(type(time_cost))
    print('totally cost for '+n+'*'+n,str(time_cost))
```

I use str to change type for time_cost, but still have error

Comment: use `str(n)` in last print statement. Because `n` is `int` not `str`

Comment: .. or use f-strings for a newer, more modern way of doing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `n` is still an `int` when you try to concatenate it with `'totally cost for '`

You must replace the last print statement with this:

`print('totally cost for '+str(n)+'*'+str(n), str(time_cost))`

It is also fine if you don't call `str()` on `time_cost` since it is a different parameter and thus `print()` automatically converts it. `n` is not converted since is concatenated explicitly using a `+` operator.
So final print can be:

`print('totally cost for '+str(n)+'*'+str(n), time_cost)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @UltraInstinct